# Can advertisements from several peripherals interfere with an existing BLE connection (Raspberry Pi 3)?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I'm working with Noble JS (a Node BLE library) on a Raspberry Pi 3 and a few different peripherals that advertise data. I'm mostly asking for a high level explanation on BLE of what may be happening between my devices.

Device A advertises and the RPi3 scans and connects to it, then scans again concurrently for more connections. If device A has no data to send to the pi, a disconnect occurs. As long as device A is in range of the pi, the pi will try to connect to device A. Thus we often see the following: pi + device A connects, pi asks for services and characteristics, pi learns there is no data to receive, pi initiates disconnect, repeat.

While the above is happening, I have ~20 of device B which are each advertising data that device A receives and processes. This is the data that device A will send to the pi on a successful connection. However, having so many of device B firing advertisements like this causes the pi to sometimes completely stall, I believe due to a corrupted connection due to interference. According to noble, a disconnect occurs immediately after a connection before the stall (this is not typical as the pi is supposed to ask for services and characteristics before disconnecting). The kicker is that after this 'disconnect,' according to device A and hcitool on the pi, the connection is still active. Thus Noble believes the pi has disconnected from device A and tries to connect again when it receives another advertisement. Then it apparently connects again and after trying to subscribe to device A's characteristics, I get a `0x0c` command disallowed status and noble stalls. Device A must be moved out of range of the pi to disconnect.

I can sometimes get just 1 of device B to cause this error, but the error is more likely to occur the more of device B is firing off advertisements. When device B is not present at all, this error does not seem to occur.

I have a crude workaround for this problem but it's less than ideal. Is this just the nature of BLE? Is the connection between device A and the pi subject to interference or corrupt connections due to device B or is my theory wrong on what is happening between devices?

Comment: There should be no RF interference, advertising happens on dedicated frequencies (channels) which are not the same as the ones used during connection. And the BLE protocol is designed to change the channel during connection if the channel is overloaded.

Comment: It's probably just a bug in noble. BLE can't stall since it has timeouts everywhere.